# Proving the equality in the attached Image

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, symmetric-matrices, finite-element-method

I am trying to learn the mathematics behind Finite elements as an engineer. can anyone help me with the proof below ? I have almost figured out the solution. The problem is I get a multiplication of matrices that have unequal interior dimensions and I don't Know how to proceed from there. Note that the sigma is a 2*2 symmetric matrices.

[Question: prove the equality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNwQL.png)

Here is what I have done so far:

[my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fe8H.jpg)

In the first step, I have assumed that using the transpose of the divergence vector is possible. I don't know whether this assumption is valid though.

thanks.

Comment: Good to hear that you have almost figured out the solution. If you can please add that to your post, then this question may not be immediately closed due to lack of effort

Comment: done. thanks  @Bram28

Comment: Thanks Mr. Bean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under convention that $\nabla$ is a column-vector like operator and $v$ is also a column vector:
\begin{align} 
\nabla \cdot (\sigma v) &= \nabla (\sigma v)^T = \nabla (v^T \sigma) = \begin{pmatrix} \partial_x & \partial_y \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \sigma_{11} + v_2 \sigma_{12} \\ 
v_1 \sigma_{21} + v_2 \sigma_{22} \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \partial_x(v_1 \sigma_{11} + v_2 \sigma_{12}) + \partial_y (v_1 \sigma_{21} + v_2 \sigma_{22}) \\
& = v_1 \partial_x \sigma_{11} + \sigma_{11} \partial_x v_1 + v_2 \partial_x \sigma_{21} + \sigma_{21} \partial_x v_2 \\
&+ v_1 \partial_y \sigma_{21} + \sigma_{21} \partial_y v_1 + v_2 \partial_y \sigma_{22} + \sigma_{22} \partial_y v_2 \\
&  = \partial_x(\sigma_{11})v_1 +  \partial_y(\sigma_{21})v_1 + \partial_x(\sigma_{12})v_2 + \partial_y(\sigma_{22})v_2 \\
& + \sigma_{11} \partial_x v_1 + \sigma_{12}\partial_x v_2 + \sigma_{21}\partial_y v_1 + \sigma_{22} \partial_y v_2 \\
&= \Big[\begin{pmatrix} \partial_x & \partial_y \end{pmatrix} \sigma \Big] \cdot v + \sigma \colon \Bigg[\begin{pmatrix} \partial_x \\ \partial_y \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}v_1 & v_2 \end{pmatrix} \Bigg] \\
& = \Big[\nabla^T \sigma \Big] \cdot v + \sigma \colon \nabla v^T \\
& \overset{\sigma = \sigma^T}{=} \Big[\nabla \cdot \sigma^T \Big] \cdot v + \sigma \colon \nabla v^T
\end{align}

To generalize this to multiple dimensions (and simplify things considerably), typically [index notation / einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) is employed:
\begin{align} 
\partial_i (\sigma_{ij} v_j ) \overset{\text{Prod. rule of diff.}}{=} \partial_i (\sigma_{ij} ) v_j + \sigma_{ij} \partial_i v_j \overset{\sigma = \sigma^T}{=} \partial_i (\sigma_{ji} ) v_j + \sigma_{ij} \partial_i v_j = (\nabla \cdot \sigma^T 
\big) \cdot v_j + \sigma \colon \nabla v^T\end{align}